Implementing Interactive 3D Visualization with DICOM Series, Volume Rendering, and STL Model Integration using VTK and Qt
I'm currently working on a medical imaging project where I need to implement interactive 3D visualization using DICOM series, volume rendering, and integrate an STL model representing a screw into the scene. Additionally, I aim to enable multiplanar reconstruction (MPR) and panoramic views from the 3D scene, along with slice views from the panoramic perspective.
Here's what I have achieved so far:
Successfully loaded DICOM series and implemented volume rendering.
Implemented basic multiplanar reconstruction (MPR) functionality.

However, I'm facing challenges with the following aspects of the project:
Integrating an STL or OBJ model representing a screw into the 3D scene and allowing for interactive manipulation of its position and angle.
Ensuring that changes made to the position and angle of the screw model in one view (coronal, axial, or sagittal) are accurately reflected in all other views.
Implementing panoramic views from the 3D scene and ensuring that changes in the STL model's position and angle are reflected in these panoramic views.
Enabling slice views from the panoramic perspective and ensuring that changes in the STL model's position and angle are reflected accurately in these slice views.

I'm using VTK (Visualization Toolkit) and Qt for the implementation. While I have a basic understanding of these libraries, I'm struggling with the intricacies of synchronizing the views and updating the STL model's position and angle across different perspectives.
Any guidance, code snippets, or resources that could help me address these challenges would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
What did you try?
I have successfully loaded the DICOM series and implemented volume rendering using VTK. Additionally, I have managed to integrate the STL model representing the screw into the 3D scene.
What were you expecting?
I expected to be able to manipulate the position and angle of the screw model interactively within the 3D scene. Furthermore, I anticipated that any changes made to the position and angle of the screw model in one view (such as coronal, axial, or sagittal) would be accurately reflected in all other views. Similarly, I aimed to implement panoramic views from the 3D scene and ensure that changes in the screw model's position and angle were accurately reflected in these panoramic views. Additionally, I aimed to enable slice views from the panoramic perspective and ensure that changes in the screw model's position and angle were accurately reflected in these slice views.
What actually resulted?
While I have successfully integrated the screw model into the 3D scene, I am facing challenges in synchronizing its position and angle across different perspectives. Specifically, I am struggling with ensuring that changes made to the screw model's position and angle in one view are accurately reflected in other views, including panoramic and slice views.
I'm seeking guidance on how to address these challenges and ensure seamless synchronization of the screw model's position and angle across different perspectives within the VTK and Qt framework.
Thank you for your assistance!

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly. You want to change the perspective in a vtk view and all other vtk views should also change? Do you get the changes to the vtk view via a callback and can you react to them? Can you set the perspective programmatically in a vtk view (camera position)?

I was assigned this same problem a few years back. We gave up on VTK and bought a library called Fovia. VTK doesn't (or didn't) support adding objects to the dataset. I also wrote it in QT and with Fovia it worked quite well. We could add surgical tools and objects (dental implants) and visualize them in multiple views in real time. No extra work needed as the objects are just added to the dataset.
